# How to set name in SelectDateWidget on buttons for month, year and day?

Tags: django

In forms:

```
bir_date = DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(1900, 2020), label="")
```

But until I not pressed on drop-down list for month, day or year, button looks like this (---).

How to make that not displayed (---) but displayed ('month', 'year', day)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you'll need to subclass `SelectDateWidget`. You'll see in the [django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/forms/extras/widgets.py#L42) that `none_value` isn't made available to be changed in the init function.

Here's an untested example:

```
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget

class CustomSelectDateWidget(SelectDateWidget):
    def get_none_value(self, field):
        return {
            "year": "Year",
            "month": "Month",
            "day": "Day",
        }[field]

    def create_select(self, name, field, value, val, choices):
        if 'id' in self.attrs:
            id_ = self.attrs['id']
        else:
            id_ = 'id_%s' % name
        if not (self.required and val):
            choices.insert(0, self.get_none_value(field))
        local_attrs = self.build_attrs(id=field % id_)
        s = Select(choices=choices)
        select_html = s.render(field % name, val, local_attrs)
        return select_html
```

If you wanted to make it even more flexible, you could override the init function to pass in a none_value dictionary and use that in `get_none_value` if it exists.

Comment: I don't understand how I can override init function

Comment: You just define ```def __init__(self, attrs=None, years=None, required=True):``` in the new class.

Comment: I do this but into function I don't know what must I do.